Is there any difference between stating the "alignas" keyword in struct definition VS array of struct definition?
Say I have a struct named Particle and I would like it to be aligned by 32bits, should I use the alignas keyword when I specify the struct definition, like code below:
struct alignas(32) Particle {
    // Total size: 16 bytes, but alignas(32) ensures 32-byte alignment
    float x; // 4 bytes
    float y; // 4 bytes
    float z; // 4 bytes
    float w; // 4 bytes 
};

or should I specify it in the definition for the layouts where the structs reside, like this:
alignas(32) Particle particles[8]; // Array of 8 particles, 32-byte aligned

or should I do both?

You haven't placed alignas in the correct place in the first example, but:

Aligning the first member of the struct will ensure that every instance of struct Particle is aligned according to your specification:
struct Particle  {
    alignas(32) float x; // 4 bytes
    float y; // 4 bytes
    float z; // 4 bytes
    float w; // 4 bytes 
};

struct Particle particles[8];
... = &particles[0];            // aligned to 32
... = &particles[1];            // aligned to 32


Aligning only the instance will only ensure that the first instance in your array is aligned according to your specification.
struct Particle  {
    float x; // 4 bytes
    float y; // 4 bytes
    float z; // 4 bytes
    float w; // 4 bytes 
};

alignas(32) struct Particle particles[8];
... = &particles[0];            // aligned to 32
... = &particles[1];            // not aligned to 32




Thanks Ted, I did some quick tests and verified that your's is correct and mine is wrong ;)

A quick follow-up question though, I certainly ever saw that alignas is used in struct definition, is that just a meaningless usage?

@PkDrew You're welcome! You mean alignas(32) struct Particle { ... };? Yes, that will be ignored.

Got it, many thanks again for teaching.
